# ansible-playbook unable to use regex

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible version 2.7. I was practicing a task where I have to add users whose username and uid stored in var file named /home/automation/plays/vars/user_list.yml  and password for the same is stored in secrets.yml having correct content. I am also able to add user from it with with_item but with next requirement of task I need to add users whose uid stats with 1* on specified hostgroup which is called with "group_names"  i was trying match regex for the same but getting error

My requirement is add a user whose udi begins with ^1  to hostgroup "webserver"

I have used with explict uids such 1201 / 1201 which is working but not working with regex

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
     - /home/automation/plays/vars/user_list.yml    
     - secrets.yml
  tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "{{users | type_debug}},{{user_password}}"
       with_items: "{{ users }}"  
     - name: Adding Users to webserver groupwith List
       user:
        name: "{{item.username}}"
        uid:   "{{item.uid}}"
        state: absent
        remove: yes  
        password: "{{ user_password }}" 
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: wheel
        generate_ssh_key: yes
        ssh_key_bits: 2048
        ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa
       when:  item.uid  is regex("1.*")
       with_items: "{{users}}"
```

```
fatal: [ansnode_1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\")' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/automation/plays/users.yml': line 12, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       with_items: \"{{ users }}\"\n     - name: Adding Users to webserver groupwith List\n       ^ here\n"}
fatal: [ansnode_4]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\")' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/automation/plays/users.yml': line 12, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       with_items: \"{{ users }}\"\n     - name: Adding Users to webserver groupwith List\n       ^ here\n"}
fatal: [ansnode_2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\")' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/automation/plays/users.yml': line 12, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       with_items: \"{{ users }}\"\n     - name: Adding Users to webserver groupwith List\n       ^ here\n"}
fatal: [ansnode_3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\")' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if item.uid  is regex(\"1.*\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/automation/plays/users.yml': line 12, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       with_items: \"{{ users }}\"\n     - name: Adding Users to webserver groupwith List\n       ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the users have already been created and
"`the requirement is to add users whose uid begins with '1' to group 'webserver'`".

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - name: Adding users to webserver group
      user:
        name: "{{ item.username }}"
        groups: webserver
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when:  item.uid|string|first == '1'
```

**Regex**

1. The condition below is an equivalent

```yaml
      when: item.uid|string is match('^1.*$')
```

2. To match the user "`where userid ends with 5`" use

```yaml
      when: item.uid|string is match('^.*5$')
```

Comment: Thanks  Vladimir But my intital question is about use of  regex   how that is used in this say i have another task where userid ends with 5  what about that !

Comment: Thanks Vladimir below line  had helped my

Comment: when:   ( 'webserver' in  group_names  and item.uid | string   is search( "^1.*"))

Answer (score 0):

[In the official documentation for Ansible 2.7](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), there is no reference to the `regex` filter. It appears only in the [documentation for Ansible 2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), so I assume it is a new addition of that version.

According to that same documentation, `regex("1.*")` will not match the UIDs starting with "1", but all the UIDs containing "1". You will want to use `match("1.*")` instead, that should work with your version of Ansible.

Comment: Thanks @ kevin Below line had worked for i supopped we need to conver variable to String before evaluating

Comment: when: ( 'webserver' in group_names and item.uid | string is search( "^1.*"))

Answer (score 0):

With this task.

```
tasks:
- name: Create users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    group: wheel
    password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    update_password: on_create
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
  when:
    - ansible_fqdn in groups['webservers']
    - "item.uid|string|first == '1'"
```